# Calculating the expected running time of function

Tags: time-complexity

I have a question about calculating the expected running time of a given function. I understand just fine, how to calculate code fragments with cycles in them (for / while / if , etc.) but functions without them seems a bit odd to me. For example, lets say that we have the following code fragment:

```
public void Add(T item)
{
    var newArr = new T[this.arr.Length + 1];
    Array.Copy(this.arr, newArr, this.arr.Length);
    newArr[newArr.Length - 1] = item;
    this.arr = newArr;
}
```

If my logic works correctly, the function Add has a complexity of O(1), because in the best/worst/average case it will just read every line of code once, right?

Answer (score 0):

You always have to consider the time complexity of the function calls, too. I don't know how `Array.Copy` is implemented, but I'm going to guess it's `O(N)`, making the whole `Add` function `O(N)` as well. Your intuition is right, though - the *rest* of it is in fact `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple sub-operations with **O(n)** +  **O(log(n))** etc and the costliest step is the cost of the whole operation - by default big O refers to the worst case. Here as you copy the array, it is an **O(n)** operation

Answer (score 0):

Complexity is calculated following this 2 rules :

**-Calling a method (complexity+ 1)**

**-Encountering the following keywords : if, while, repeat, for, &&, ||, catch, case, etc … (complexity+ 1)**

In your case , given you are trying to copy an array and not a single value , the algorithm will complete **N** copy operations  giving you an **O(N)** operation.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it helped a lot! So if I have to Array.Copy 2 times like :

Comment: So if I have to Array.Copy 2 times like :  Array.Copy(this.arr, newArr, index);
                                        Array.Copy(this.arr, index + 1, newArr, index, this.arr.Length - index - 1); -> this means that the second Array.Copy will be O(2n) and the function will be again O(n) ?

Comment: Yes , it will be O(n) .

Comment: Okay, thanks again! Now it all seems to be much clearer.